# Add and merge rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

This table I draw has two columns "Team" and "Members". What I want to ask is; by clicking the plus icon in Team column, how to add a new row (consisting of both columns) while by clicking the plus icon in Members column, how to add a row just in Members column without adding a row in Team?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<table class="table table-bordered w-auto">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Team</th>
  <th>Members</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myList">

    <script>
      function addrow(){
        var row = "<tr><td class='form-group' style='position: relative'><input type='team' class='form-control' id='team' placeholder='Enter the team'><div class='justify-content-center' style='position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;'></div></td><td class='form-group' style='position: relative'><input type='members' class='form-control' id='members' placeholder='Enter the members'><div class='justify-content-center' style='position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;'></div></td></tr>";
        document.getElementById("myList").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);
        }
    </script>

<tr>
  <td class="form-group" style="position: relative">
    <input type="team" class="form-control" id="team" placeholder="Enter the team">
    <div class="justify-content-center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;">
        <a onclick="addrow()" class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="form-group" style="position: relative">
    <input type="members" class="form-control" id="members" placeholder="Enter the members">
    <div class="justify-content-center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;">
        <a class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a>
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried this in javascript but isn't working properly. function addrow(){  var row = "";  document.getElementById("myList").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row); } <a onclick="addrow()" class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#">

Comment: As you can see it is adding rows below plus icon, and I want them above.

Comment: To preserve table integrity, there must be equal count of cells on each row, otherwise columns must be balanced with `rowspan` attributes. You've to create the cells individually instead of the immutable string you're using now, keep count of the rows in the columns, and add `rowspan` attributes to the cells accordingly. Also, create `tfooter`, and place the buttons on their own row in the footer. Use `tbody` as the element where you're appending the rows. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: It might be easier to create a new `tbody` for each team, and then add members to that tbody, and increase `rowspan` of the team when adding a new member. This way it would be a bit easier to collect the data when all the teams and members are entered.

Comment: I will try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bit more complex solution for this, creating a new row from a string is not flexible enough. Rows in a column must also be in balance, extra rows in a single column must be compensated with `rowspan` attributes of the cells in other columns.

It might be also easier to collect the results of the entered teams and members into data, if every team would have its own `tbody` element in the table. Something like this:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#list'),
  teamBut = document.querySelector('#addTeam'),
  memBut = document.querySelector('#addMem');
let activeTeam = table.tBodies[0];

// Adds a Team row
function addTeam() {
  const tbody = createElement('tbody'),
    row = tbody.insertRow(-1),
    cellT = row.insertCell(-1),
    cellM = row.insertCell(-1),
    inputT = createElement('input', {type: 'team', placeholder: 'Enter the team', class: 'form-control'}),
    inputM = createElement('input', {type: 'members', placeholder: 'Enter the members', class: 'form-control'});  
  cellT.append(inputT);
  cellM.append(inputM);  
  table.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', tbody);
  activeTeam = tbody;
  activeTeam.querySelector('td').append(teamBut);
  activeTeam.querySelector('td:last-child').append(memBut);
}

// Adds a member column
function addMember() {
  const memberRow = createElement('tr'),
    memberCell = createElement('td', {class: 'form-group'}),
    teamCell = activeTeam.querySelector('td'),
    rowspan = (teamCell.rowSpan || 0) + 1,
    input = createElement('input', {type: 'members', placeholder: 'Enter the members', class: 'form-control'});
  memberRow.append(memberCell);
  memberCell.append(input);
  activeTeam.append(memberRow);
  teamCell.rowSpan = rowspan;
}

// Add ability to change the active team
table.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const tbody = e.target.closest('tbody');
  if (!tbody) {return;}
  activeTeam = tbody;
  activeTeam.querySelector('td').append(teamBut);
  activeTeam.querySelector('td:last-child').append(memBut);
});

// Creates an HTMLElement with the passed attributes
function createElement (tag, attrs = {}) {
  const element = document.createElement(tag);
  for (const [attr, val] of Object.entries(attrs)) {
    element.setAttribute(attr, val);
  }
  return element;
}
```

```css
#list td {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="list" class="table table-bordered w-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Members</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="form-group">
        <input type="team" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the team">
        <div id="addTeam" class="justify-content-center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;">
          <a onclick="addTeam()" class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a>
        </div>
     </td>
      <td class="form-group">
        <input type="members" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the members">
        <div id="addMem" class="justify-content-center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;">
          <a onclick="addMember()" class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There's also a feature, which allows you to select active team by clicking on the team in the table.

---

**WARNING!**

The utility function `createElement` is insecure, when passing arguments from untrusted source (ex. third-party or user entered data). Always filter the arguments before passing to the function.

Comment: @Ismail86 I've edited the buttons to appear to the active team instead of them being in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Would You like to add input Members column without adding team input?

[image]

in function of addrow you maybe change
var row = ""

OR You can use An HTML table with a table cell that spans two columns.